# Data Frame Subset in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset/filter in a data frame.

```
Col1 Col2

A   23454,34543
B   23456
C   34543,34532
```

I want to subset and get Row B alone example : B 23456, based on the length of Col2 either as grep or some other function.

Comment: What do you mean by *the length of Col2*? Is it comma?

Comment: `df[!grepl(',', df$Col2),]`?

Comment: I have too many columns for this data set and I want to subset using the grep conditions on col2 based on its value. " 12345" ,"12345,45455", "23434,43434,34563"

Comment: What's a condition?

Comment: Perhaps share a slightly larger example data set (formatted using `dput()` would be the best) and an example of the expected output. Also show any examples of what you have tried so far.